# A lot of catch blocks, but in all of them the same function

Tags: c#, .net, exception, try-catch

What if I had something like this:

```
try
{
   //work
}
catch (ArgumentNullException e)
{
   HandleNullException();
   Logger.log("ArgumentNullException " + e);
   DoSomething();
}
catch (SomeOtherException e)
{
   HandleSomeOtherException();
   Logger.log("SomeOtherException " + e);
   DoSomething();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
   HandleException();
   Logger.log("Exception " + e);
   DoSomething();
}
```

Now as we can see, I'm trying to handle exceptions for some different cases. BUT whenever an exception is raised, I'm always calling the method `DoSomething()` at the end. Is there a smarter way to call `DoSomething()` if there is an exception? If I added a `finally` block and called `DoSomething()` there, it would always be called, even when there is no exception. Any suggestions?

Comment: @JanesAbouChleih Then instead of having redundant code for calling a method, he'd have redundant code to set a boolean.

Comment: @Eve: Replacing redundant method calls with redundant setting of a flag can be an improvement nevertheless. Let's assume that the OP at some point wants to replace `DoSomething` with `DoSomethingElse`. With the flag in place, s/he will only have to modify the code in one place. Without a flag, possibly more than one location would have to be modified in the same fashion. What if the OP overlooked one of them? So IMHO introducing a flag improves DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) and eliminates a potential error source.

Comment: @stakx With my solution (to have just one `catch` block, see my answer), I think he eliminates the "DRY" (code duplication) without introducing a painful boolean like `didAnyCatchBlockRun`.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: See your answer for my reply to your above comment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> *If I added a `finally` block and called `DoSomething()` there, it would always be called, even when there is no exception.*

What you are looking for is known in the [CLI standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm) (partition IIA, chapter 18) as a [fault handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11987953/how-are-cil-fault-clauses-different-from-catch-clauses-in-c). Although .NET implements them, the C# language does not directly support them. However, they can be emulated:

```
bool success = false;
try
{
    …
    success = true;
}
catch (…)
{
    …
}
…
finally
{
    if (!success)
    {
        DoSomething();
    }
}
```

Note that there is no need to set the flag inside every `catch` handler, as some answers here suggest. Simply negate the test, and you only need to set the flag once, at the end of the `try` block.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the following code which actually *does* remove redundancies.

```
try
{
    //work
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Handle(e);
}
```

Where the `Handle` method is:

```
static void Handle(Exception e)
{
    var exceptionType = e.GetType();
    //Use an if/else block, or use a Dictionary<Type, Action>
    //to operate on your exception
    Logger.log(exceptionType + " " + e);
    DoSomething();
}
```

Comment: IMO this and @stakx approach is the best +1 for both.

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing now is about as good as it gets.

If you need to call this function whenever an exception happens, but not otherwise, and you must have different code for handling different exceptions, than this is the best that can be done.

Comment: If most of what is to be done does not depend on what eception type is being handled, he can have just one `catch` block, and cope with the small differences by saying `if (e is ArgumentNullException)` and so on. See my answer if it's not clear what I mean.

Answer (score 2):

You could set a boolean whenever a exception is thrown, use `finally` and check for the boolean. (Or do the opposite and set the boolean only when no exception is thrown, as shown below:)

```
bool noException = false;
try
{
    //work
    noException = true;
}
catch (ArgumentNullException e)
{
    HandleNullException();
    Logger.log("ArgumentNullException " + e);
}
catch (SomeOtherException e)
{
    HandleSomeOtherException();
    Logger.log("SomeOtherException " + e);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    HandleException();
    Logger.log("Exception " + e);
}
finally
{
    if (!noException)
        DoSomething();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not just:

```
try
{
    //work
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    if (e is ArgumentNullException)
      HandleNullException();
    else if (e is SomeOtherException)
      HandleSomeOtherException();
    else
      HandleException();
    Logger.log(e.GetType().Name + " " + e);
    DoSomething();
}
```

The type name logged will be the actual runtime type, so for example `"IndexOutOfRangeException"` may be logged instead of just `"Exception"` if you're in case three, but I see this as an improvement over what you have now.

**Edit:** Above code looks awful with the `if`–`else if` logic checking on types. If we introduced polymorphism, it could be more beautiful:

```
try
{
    //work
}
catch (HandleableException e)
{
    e.Handle();  // this calls a **virtual** method, each override does what's relevant
    Logger.log(e.GetType().Name + " " + e);
    DoSomething();
}
```

Of course, if some of the `Exception` classes in question cannot be modified by us, it would be impossible to give them a `Handle()` method. The `.Handle()` could also be an extension method (instead of a `virtual` instance method), but then the type checking (ugly code) would have to be done inside that method. Then this becomes quite similar to Eve's answer.

Comment: -1. This solves the problem at the expense of introducing a worse issue into the code than what the OP was trying to get rid of! `if (… is FooException) … else if (… is BarException) …` goes against two fundamental things: **(1)** the very reason why you can have several `catch` handlers; and **(2)** OOP polymorphism. Concerning this last point, see e.g. the 2008 talk, ['Conditionals and Polymorphism' by Misko Hevery](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4F72VULWFvc).

Comment: @stakx The code wasn't too beautiful to begin with. Do you love several `catch` blocks (some of which are related, like `Exception` is base class of `SomeOtherException`, while `SomeOtherException` is **not** a base class of `ArgumentNullException`) very much? In my opinion the `if (e is T) … else if (e is S)` and so on, _is_ ugly, but several `catch` blocks is _equally_ ugly. And I don't like the solution of "factoring out" logic common to many `catch` blocks and putting it into a `finally` block with an obscure `if` in it. `finally` blocks are designed for things that must run in any case.

Comment: +1 for your latest addition. Note however that a bunch of extension methods `Handle(this SomeExceptionType)` will not work as you might expect: For instance, if you have both `Handle(this Exception)` and `Handle(this FooException)`, only the first one will ever get called, even for `FooException` instances. This is because `e` in `e.Handle()` has the static (compile-time) type `Exception`. The method to be called is resolved statically by the compiler, based static type information. That is, there is no virtual dispatch with extension methods.

Comment: @stakx You're absolutely correct about that. I made one more edit to remove the misleading part. The only way to get overload resolution based on the actual runtime type is to defer the binding until runtime (can be done with the `dynamic` keyword, `Handle((dynamic)e);`).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
Exception caughtException = null;
try {
    ...
} catch(ExceptionType1 e1) {
    ...
    caughtException = e1;
} catch(ExceptionType2 e2) {
    ...
    caughtException = e2;
} catch(ExceptionType3 e3) {
    ...
    caughtException = e3;
}
if (caughtException != null) {
    // Put your common exception code here
    DoSomenthing();
    // You can pass caughtException to functions, too
    LogException(caughtException);
}
```

`caughtException` will be `null` unless an exception is caught. You can use it to decide to call `DoSomenthing` or not.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
try
{
    // code
    return response;
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    handleException(e);
} 
public void handleException(Exception e) 
{
    if (e is ArgumentNullException) 
    {
        Logger.log("");
        HandleArgumentNullException();
    } 
    else if (e is SomeOtherException) 
    {
        Logger.log("");
        HandleSomeOtherException();
    } 
    else if (..)
    {
    }
    else
    {
        Logger.log("");
        HandleException();
    }
    DoSomething();
}
```

The common handleException method will be called only when there is an exception thrown and thus DoSomething() will be executed only in that case

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I have modified the details in my answer